# How to prevent a span of one symbol from appearing in the first of the line?

Tags: html, css, word-break

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  word-break: break-word;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span>a</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>hellll</span><span>.</span>
</span>
```

Acutal behavior:

```
a hellll
.
```

The behavior I want to achieve:

```
a 
hellll.
```

In practice, my input will be an array from a random article like `['a', '&nbsp', 'hellll', '.']`, which is a result from separating the article by words.

Is it possible when all words and symbols are separated into individual spans?

Comment: Is your text static or dynamic?

Comment: @CristianTraìna dynamic. Normally an article. My idea is to highlight every word when clicked (with no space and symbols)

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54557577/8620333

Comment: I don't think it's possible. `break-word` only works if the symbols and characters are connected. Using spans separates them. You could do some kind of lookup in the array to see if the next character is a symbol or a word, and in case it's a symbol, add it to the span, otherwise, close it and open a new one. Maybe?

Comment: @user6456568 do you want to break the line every time `&nbsp;` apears in the array?

Comment: No. I just want to aviod the first element in each line is a symbol.

Answer (score -1):

either change span to a block element or add style to it and set it to block

```css
.block {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="block">a</span><span>hellll</span><span>.</span>
</span>
```